# Can you pass in a string collection into a flow using a URL?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have a list of record Ids that need to be pushed through to a flow using a URL. Is this possible?

I have created a new resource to hold these string values and have ensured that the "Allow Multiple Values" checkbox is checked. The resource is called "recordIds".

[image]

I have then been trying to use the following URL -

> https://BASE_URL/flow/Test_Flow?recordIds=0013h000007JTgiAAG,0013h000007JTggAAG

The values do make it through to the resource and I can see that it gets populated based on a screen which shows the following results -

[image]

But as can be seen when I do a count on the recordIds collection it shows a value of 1. It seems the entire string gets considered as one record.

If there is no way of passing in the strings as a collection is there a way of parsing the string out and then creating a collection inside of flow once the string has been received?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to init a collection variable with multiple values, it is necessary to specify the same URL parameter multiple times, for each of the values.

For example:

```
/flow/Test_Flow?recordIds=0013h000007JTgiAAG&recordIds=0013h000007JTggAAG
```

More information can be found in official salesforce documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url_variable.htm&type=5).

Comment: thank you. Worked perfectly.